# echo variable with variable from included file

Tags: php, include

so basically what I can't get through is to echo a variable, that contains variable from included file.

**Explanation:**

I have 3 files:

```
index.php
system/functions.php
system/config.php
```

each file is including the other file so they work like one (except index)

**system/functions.php** contains:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/config.php';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/connection.php';
```

**system/config.php** contains:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/functions.php';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/system/connection.php';
```

there's nothing wrong with it and they work together without problems, they can pass variables between themselves successfuly. **BUT**

When I want to:

```
echo $message;
```

On the **index.php**, the output is only the string from the variable, and *skips* other variables from included files...

In this case, the **functions.php** file contains

```
$message = $varfromconfig."Some String";
```

where **config.php** contains

```
$varfromconfig = "someword ";
```

and when I echo the `$message` to **index** page, only the *string* `Some String` is returned, without the config variable... Why? (Should return `someword Some String`)

Thank you.

Of course, the index.php contains both the config and the functions...

```
include_once 'system/config.php';
include_once 'system/connection.php';
include_once 'system/functions.php';
```

Comment: you don't get any errors? error reporting is on?

Comment: Activate error reporting (`error_reporting( E_ALL ); ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );` at top of your script) to see if `$varfromconfig` is empty or not set.

Comment: can you do a var_dump() at $varfromconfig after you set $message and post here?

Comment: @Jeff , error reporting is on since my programming life. so no, no errors.

Comment: @rvbarreto `var_dump($varfromconfig)` reuturns `NULL`.. only on **functions** page...? Could it be a bug?

Comment: So what I actually noticed is that `$varfromconfig` is **undefined** don't know the reason...

Comment: @StevenDropper I guess I figured it out. Check my answer and tells me if it works.

Comment: Go through the execution order with pen and paper if needed. The answer is very likely simply that your double inclusion causes the variable not to exist when you try to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this at index.php:

```
//include_once 'system/config.php'; remove this include from index.php
include_once 'system/connection.php';
include_once 'system/functions.php';
```

**OR**, do this:

```
include_once 'system/config.php'; remove this include from index.php
include_once 'system/connection.php';
include 'system/functions.php'; //not include_once
```

You have a loop when you insert both. I imagine your relation between **config.php** and **functions.php** can be more complex then you wrote here, so I will try to detail what is happening so you can find another solution, if needed.

Right after you run **index.php**, it calls for **config.php**. Then, inside **config.php**, this happens:

**config.php** insert **functions.php**, but then **functions.php** insert **config.php**, and **config.php** insert **funtions.php** again and this will keep forever. So php interpreter just break the loop before it happens and import only **functions.php** from inside **config.php**, but don't import **config.php** from inside **functions.php** from inside **config.php**. (damn inception)

So now we have just passed line 1 of **index.php** and have imported first **config.php** from **index.php** and then **functions.php** from **config.php**. The interpreter had first red **functions.php**, loaded its variables, then went to **config.php** and loaded its variables.

Thus, first from **functions.php**, it runs `$message = $varfromconfig."Some String";`. Once **config.php** wasn't interpreted yet and $varfromconfig is still empty, it assing "Some String" to `$message`. Then it runs `$varfromconfig = "someword ";`, but without having it assigned to `$message`, because $message assignment was already done.

On the seccond line, connections.php is imported, and then on third line it tries to import **functions.php**, but **functions.php** was already inserted. So `include_once` don't let it be imported.

To solve this, once the variable in **functions.php** require **config.php** to run first, you just call for **functions.php** at **index.php** and let **functions.php** call **config.php** by itself. The other solution is to use `include` and not `include_once` to insert **functions.php** and let it be interpreted two times.

Comment: I understand now, but what if both files need each other? functions include config but config include functions, isnt it in a loop again?...

Comment: @StevenDropper That's called a *circular dependency* and is madness. One thing can't depend on the other when the other also depends on it. You'll have to do some refactoring there.